# How can i use Date-time operator?

Tags: c#

at VS I press the `F12` key on `DateTime` and at the end of the `DateTime` Struct I see these:

```csharp
        public static DateTime operator +(DateTime d, TimeSpan t);
        public static TimeSpan operator -(DateTime d1, DateTime d2);              
        public static DateTime operator -(DateTime d, TimeSpan t);
        public static bool operator ==(DateTime d1, DateTime d2);
        public static bool operator !=(DateTime d1, DateTime d2);       
        public static bool operator <(DateTime t1, DateTime t2);
        public static bool operator >(DateTime t1, DateTime t2);
        public static bool operator <=(DateTime t1, DateTime t2);
        public static bool operator >=(DateTime t1, DateTime t2);
```

always I compare `DateTime` in this way. for example:

```csharp
            DateTime date1=DateTime.Now;
            DateTime date2=DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2);

            if (date1 > date2)
            {
                // date1 greater than date2
            }
            else
            {  
                // date2 greater than date1
            }
```

but how can I use those methods? can somebody give an example of that? thanks in advance

Comment: Use other operators same as you use `>`, after all `>` is just one of the operators. So, use `d1 - d2`, `d1 == d2`, `d1 != d2` etc

Comment: that methods are called when you do date1 > date 2 , date1 + date2 etc

Comment: shouldn`t I pass the DateTime like input to method?

Comment: Do a search on the msdn source for operator : https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,df6b1eba7461813b  The source compares tick value.

Comment: They are not `methods` they are [`operators`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/). Also you can override those operators check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading

Comment: no. Expression `d1 > d2` calls `public static bool operator >(DateTime t1, DateTime t2);`. See  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/comparison-operators#operator-overloadability

Comment: When you use `date1 > date2` it will invoke `public static bool operator >(DateTime t1, DateTime t2);` with `t1 as date1` & `t2 as date2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example you are using method operator `>`. This methods are definied operators for class `DateTime`. You can implement operators for your own class to save time on coding. Here you have documentation about [operator overloading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading). I hope it helps you undestand it more.